# JPA Deserilization Exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having following domain but while retrieving the same from JPARepository giving me Deserialization Exception.

Tried making fields even transient but the same issue. What am i doing wrong here?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123123212141221421L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name="login", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 60, max = 60) 
    @Column(name = "password_hash",length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name="email", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column( name="activated", nullable = false)
    private boolean activated = false;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 5)
    @Column(name = "lang_key", length = 5)
    private String langKey;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "activation_key", length = 20)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String activationKey;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "reset_key", length = 20)
    private String resetKey;

    @Column(name = "reset_date", nullable = true)
    private ZonedDateTime resetDate = null;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "jhi_user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private  Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private  Set<PersistentToken> persistentTokens = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean getActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public String getActivationKey() {
        return activationKey;
    }

    public void setActivationKey(String activationKey) {
        this.activationKey = activationKey;
    }

    public String getResetKey() {
        return resetKey;
    }

    public void setResetKey(String resetKey) {
        this.resetKey = resetKey;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getResetDate() {
       return resetDate;
    }

    public void setResetDate(ZonedDateTime resetDate) {
       this.resetDate = resetDate;
    }

    public String getLangKey() {
        return langKey;
    }

    public void setLangKey(String langKey) {
        this.langKey = langKey;
    }

    public Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public Set<PersistentToken> getPersistentTokens() {
        return persistentTokens;
    }

    public void setPersistentTokens(Set<PersistentToken> persistentTokens) {
        this.persistentTokens = persistentTokens;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        User user = (User) o;

        if (!login.equals(user.login)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return login.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
            "login='" + login + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", activated='" + activated + '\'' +
            ", langKey='" + langKey + '\'' +
            ", activationKey='" + activationKey + '\'' +
            "}";
    }
}
```

i hope you'll help me with this i kept searching for too long and just don't know what to do now .

Comment: You haven't supplied the exception thrown and one can't say if it's hibernate or Jackson serialization problem, but if you are using hibernate version prior to 5.0, then `ZonedDateTime` (and Java 8 Date API types in general) is not supported (`ZonedDateTimeType` added in hibernate 5.0)

Comment: I think i got the problem but putting the solution for community. It looks to be ZonedTime issue in java8. If you change it to timestamp the exception disapperas